# Firebase facebook authentication not working

Tags: angularjs, facebook, firebase

I am trying facebook authentication in angularJs but every time I got this error[image]

here is my code

```
![var app=angular.module('myApp',['firebase']);
app.controller("SampleCtrl", function($scope) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://socialauthi.firebaseio.com/data");

    $scope.tryLogin=function() {
        ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Login Failed!", error);
            } else {
                console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I have also added facebook app id and app secret in firebase.
Using localhost

[image]

Comment: URL set by you in facebook is not matching with "https://socialauthi.firebaseio.com/data". Please check your URL in  facebook -> setting -> basic ->  App Domains

Comment: Thank you .But when I am trying to add https://socialauthi.firebaseio.com/data in App Domains . This Error showing.                                                                                              This must be derived from Secure Canvas URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL, Mobile Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Check and correct the following domains: socialauthi.firebaseio.com/data                                                  I just want authenticate

Comment: The URL you should be entering in Facebook's app settings is along the lines of `https://auth.firebase.com/v2/<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>/auth/facebook/callback` Please follow the instructions in paragraph 2 here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/facebook.html

Comment: I did this like you shared

Comment: It should be `https://auth.firebase.com/v2/socialauthi/auth/facebook/callback`

Comment: thank you Frank van Puffelen